# why an instance member in super class cannot accessed by Super class reference in Subclass in another package

Tags: java

I have a Super-class A in `PackageOne` and a Sub-class B which is in  `PackageTwo`.

```
package PackageOne;

public class A {        
protected number = 0;        
}
```

Second Class is here

```
package PackageTwo;

public class B extends A {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
       A a = new A();
       System.out.println(a.number);// Here is the error occurs        
    }        
}
```

Error is `The field Person.name is not visible`;

As I know a protected member can be accessed by a super-class reference, but why the error occurs.

Comment: In this case `B` isn't even a subclass of `A`. Why would you *expect* to have access? (Also, please take more care when formatting your post in future. I've fixed it up this time, but look at the preview before you hit post.)

Comment: I cant see any inheritance (before edit)

Comment: @maskacovnik i edited my code check now

Comment: Where is "The field Person.name"? Generally what doesn't exists isn't visible.

Comment: @MikeCAT OP obviously meant "The field **A.number** is not visible", but instead pasted the actual error instead of the error that occurs in his example.

Answer (score 2):

[Controlling Access to Members of a Class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)

> The `protected` modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by a subclass of its class in another package.

Because it is `protected` member. You need to `extend` (inheritance) the class to access the `protected` members of a class in another package.

Instead of accessing via `A` access it via `B`. Once you extend the class `A` it becomes the part of class `B`. You cannot access it using the reference of `A`.

```
public class B extends A {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    B b = new B();  // create the instance of B.
    System.out.println(b.number);  // access via the b.
  }
}
```

You are also missing the data type in class `A`:

```
public class A {
  protected int number = 0;
}
```

---

In the same package you can reference the members using the instance reference. Check the below code:

```
package PackageOne;

public class C {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    A a = new A();
    System.out.println(a.number); // this works.
  }
}
```

Comment: This won't work if `A` and `B` are in different packages, as OP states in his question.

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula I got it. and updated the answer.

Comment: Now it works, even though that's a little different from OP's situation.

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula It is different, because what OP is trying to do is completely wrong and compilation error in java.

Comment: Yup. That's basically what I wrote in my answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you are in a different package, you can't access the field of another instance. You can only access the field within yourself.

Class `A`:

```
package a;

public class A {
    protected int i;
}
```

Class `B`:

```
package b;

public class B extends A {

    void m() {
        A a = new A();
        System.out.println(a.i); // error here!

        System.out.println(i);   // but no error here
    }
}
```

If `A` and `B` were in the same package, though, there would be no error whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

Protected methods can only be accessible through inheritance in subclasses outside the package. And hence the second approach tryMeProtected(); works.

The code below wont compile because we are not calling the inherited version of protected method.

```
Example
Class1 c = new ClassA();
c.tryMeProtected(); // ERROR: tryMeProtected() has protected access in ClassA
```

Follow [This stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14404260/call-protected-method-from-a-subclass-of-another-instance-of-different-packages) for more explaination.

Answer (score 0):

That's not how inheritance works. You don't make a class a subclass of another one by creating an instance of it.

You have to `extend` it.

```
public class B extends A
```

This will allow you to access `protected` fields. However, you will have to `import PackageOne.A` to do this.

**EDIT**

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/215497/difference-between-public-default-protected-and-private?rq=1) SO answer by @David Segonds on how these keywords work

```
            | Class | Package | Subclass | World
————————————+———————+—————————+——————————+———————
protected   |  y    |    y    |    y     |   n
```

You have to be a subclass or in the same package to access these properties.

From the [official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html):

> The `protected` modifier specifies that the member can only be accessed within its own package (as with package-private) and, in addition, by a subclass of its class in another package.

Comment: @ThiagoPorciúncula Thanks for bringing it to my attention. See my edited answer